# Как использовать ангуляровское делегирование событий?

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Помогите пожалуйста отрефакторить кусочек кода. Я получил данные из json и на основе их построил табличку. После клика на определённой ячейке табличка выводится модальное окно с информацией о той ячейке, на которой произошёл клик.

Вот код компонента:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  private participants: Participant[] = [];
  private GENDERS: Object = {
    0: 'female',
    1: 'male',
    2: 'android'
  };

  constructor(private http: Http) { 
    this.participants = localStorage.participants ? JSON.parse(localStorage.participants) : [];
    //console.log(this.participants);
  };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getParticipants();
  };

  private getParticipants(): void {
    let result: any;

    if(this.participants.length != 0) {
      console.log('empty', this.participants);
    } else {
      //console.log('full');
      this.http.get(Config.host + 'assets/json/participants.json').subscribe(
      data => {   
        //console.log(data);  
        let participantsRaw = JSON.parse(data['_body']);
        let participants: any[] = [];

        for(var prop in participantsRaw) {
          if (!participantsRaw.hasOwnProperty(prop)) continue;
          participants.push(participantsRaw[prop]);
        }

        this.participants = participants;                                                                                                                           
        console.log('this.participants', this.participants); 
      }, 
      err => {
        console.log('err')         
      });
    } 
  };  

  private handlerClick(event): void {   
    let tagName = event.target.tagName    
    let elId = (tagName == 'SPAN') ? event.target.parentElement.id : event.target.id;  

    let rowId = elId.split('_')[1];
    let colId = elId.split('_')[2];

    console.log(elId, rowId, colId);

    prompt('Введите свойство ' + colId + ' для участника с ID=' + rowId);
  };

}
```

Вот код шаблона:

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="body" (click)="handlerClick($event)">
        <tr *ngFor="let p of participants; let i = index;" id="line_{{ p?.id }}">
            <td class="col-0" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_{{ p?.id }}">{{ p?.id }}</td>
            <td class="col-names" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_names">
                <span>{{ p?.fname }}</span>
                <span>{{ p?.mname }}</span>
                <span>{{ p?.lname }}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="col-position" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_position">{{ p?.position }}</td>
            <td class="col-gender" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_gender">{{ GENDERS[p?.gender] }}</td>
            <td class="col-married" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_married">{{ p?.married ? 'yes' : 'no' }}</td>
            <td class="col-city" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_city">{{ p?.city }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Результат выглядит [так](https://i.yapx.ru/Z01Z.png).

Проблема в том, что я в обработчике клика `handlerClick()` использовал нативный JavaScript. А мне хотелось бы использовать средства только ангуляра.

Покажите как можно переписать `handlerClick()`. Возможно, придётся внести изменения и в разметку, меня это тоже устроит.

Если нужно, то все исходники [здесь](https://github.com/zlodiak/ng4_table/tree/367a3f5ab53a1addf796b2a8f62e1e42e3fa2e76).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вешайте обработчик не на всю таблицу и передавайте необходимые данные в функцию без обращений к id

```
  private handlerClick(rowId, colId): void {   
    prompt('Введите свойство ' + colId + ' для участника с ID=' + rowId);
  };
```

```
<table class="table">
    <tbody class="body">
        <tr *ngFor="let p of participants; let i = index;" id="line_{{ p?.id }}">
            <td class="col-0" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_{{ p?.id }}" (click)="handlerClick(p.id, 'id')">{{ p?.id }}</td>
            <td class="col-names" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_names" (click)="handlerClick(p.id, 'names')">
                <span>{{ p?.fname }}</span>
                <span>{{ p?.mname }}</span>
                <span>{{ p?.lname }}</span>
            </td>
            <td class="col-position" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_position" (click)="handlerClick(p.id, 'position')">{{ p?.position }}</td>
            <td class="col-gender" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_gender" (click)="handlerClick(p.id, 'gender')">{{ GENDERS[p?.gender] }}</td>
            <td class="col-married" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_married" (click)="handlerClick(p.id, 'married')">{{ p?.married ? 'yes' : 'no' }}</td>
            <td class="col-city" id="line_{{ p?.id }}_city" (click)="handlerClick(p.id, 'city')">{{ p?.city }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

P.S. `id="line_{{ p?.id }}_{{ p?.id }}"` - Думаю, "Введите свойство 131 для участника с ID=131" это не то, что нужно

Comment: Поставил галочку потому что формально проблема решена, но решение не DRY